# Slicing and broadcasting multidimensional arrays in Julia : meshgrid example

Tags: multidimensional-array, slice, julia

I recently started learning Julia by coding a simple implementation of Self Organizing Maps. I want the size and dimensions of the map to be specified by the user, which means I can't really use for loops to work on the map arrays because I don't know in advance how many layers of loops I will need. So I absolutely need broadcasting and slicing functions that work on arrays of arbitrary dimensions.

Right now, I need to construct an array of indices of the map. Say my map is defined by an array of size `mapsize = (5, 10, 15)`, I need to construct an array `indices` of size `(3, 5, 10, 15)` where `indices[:, a, b, c]` should return `[a, b, c]`.

I come from a Python/NumPy background, in which the solution is already given by a specific "function", mgrid :

```
indices = numpy.mgrid[:5, :10, :15]
print indices.shape # gives (3, 5, 10, 15)
print indices[:, 1, 2, 3] gives [1, 2, 3]
```

I didn't expect Julia to have such a function on the get-go, so I turned to broadcasting. In NumPy, broadcasting is based on a set of rules that I find quite clear and logical. You can use arrays of different dimensions in the same expression as long as the sizes in each dimension match or one of it is 1 :

```
(5, 10, 15)   broadcasts to  (5, 10, 15) 
   (10,  1)

(5,  1, 15)   also broadcasts to (5, 10, 15) 
(1, 10,  1)
```

To help with this, you can also use numpy.newaxis or None to easily add new dimensions to your array :

```
array = numpy.zeros((5, 15))
array[:,None,:] has shape (5, 1, 15)
```

This helps broadcast arrays easily :

```
A = numpy.arange(5)
B = numpy.arange(10)
C = numpy.arange(15)
bA, bB, bC = numpy.broadcast_arrays(A[:,None,None], B[None,:,None], C[None,None,:])
bA.shape == bB.shape == bC.shape = (5, 10, 15)
```

Using this, creating the `indices` array is rather straightforward :

```
indices = numpy.array(numpy.broadcast_arrays(A[:,None,None], B[None,:,None], C[None,None,:]))
(indices == numpy.mgrid[:5,:10,:15]).all() returns True
```

The general case is of course a bit more complicated, but can be worked around using list comprehension and slices :

```
arrays = [ numpy.arange(i)[tuple([None if m!=n else slice(None) for m in range(len(mapsize))])] for n, i in enumerate(mapsize) ]
indices = numpy.array(numpy.broadcast_arrays(*arrays))
```

So back to Julia. I tried to apply the same kind of rationale and ended up achieving the equivalent of the `arrays` list of the code above. This ended up being rather simpler than the NumPy counterpart thanks to the compound expression syntax :

```
arrays = [ (idx = ones(Int, length(mapsize)); idx[n] = i;reshape([1:i], tuple(idx...))) for (n,i)=enumerate(mapsize) ]
```

Now I'm stuck here, as I don't really know how to apply the broadcasting to my list of generating arrays here... The `broadcast[!]` functions ask for a function f to apply, and I don't have any. I tried using a for loop to try forcing the broadcasting:

```
indices = Array(Int, tuple(unshift!([i for i=mapsize], length(mapsize))...))
for i=1:length(mapsize)
    A[i] = arrays[i]
end
```

But this gives me an error : `ERROR: convert has no method matching convert(::Type{Int64}, ::Array{Int64,3})`

Am I doing this the right way? Did I overlook something important? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Broadcasting in Julia has been modelled pretty much on broadcasting in NumPy, so you should hopefully find that it obeys more or less the same simple rules (not sure if the way to pad dimensions when not all inputs have the same number of dimensions is the same though, since Julia arrays are column-major).

A number of useful things like `newaxis` indexing and `broadcast_arrays` have not been implemented (yet) however. (I hope they will.) Also note that indexing works a bit differently in Julia compared to NumPy: when you leave off indices for trailing dimensions in NumPy, the remaining indices default to colons. In Julia they could be said to default to ones instead.

I'm not sure if you actually need a meshgrid function, most things that you would want to use it for could be done by using the original entries of your `arrays` array with broadcasting operations. The major reason that `meshgrid` is useful in matlab is because it is terrible at broadcasting.

But it is quite straightforward to accomplish what you want to do using the `broadcast!` function:

```
# assume mapsize is a vector with the desired shape, e.g. mapsize = [2,3,4]

N = length(mapsize)
# Your line to create arrays below, with an extra initial dimension on each array
arrays = [ (idx = ones(Int, N+1); idx[n+1] = i;reshape([1:i], tuple(idx...))) for (n,i) in enumerate(mapsize) ]

# Create indices and fill it one coordinate at a time
indices = zeros(Int, tuple(N, mapsize...))
for (i,arr) in enumerate(arrays)
    dest = sub(indices, i, [Colon() for j=1:N]...)
    broadcast!(identity, dest, arr)
end
```

I had to add an initial singleton dimension on the entries of `arrays` to line up with the axes of `indices` (`newaxis` had been useful here...).
Then I go through each coordinate, create a subarray (a view) on the relevant part of `indices`, and fill it. (Indexing will default to returning subarrays in Julia 0.4, but for now we have to use `sub` explicitly).

The call to `broadcast!` just evaluates the identity function `identity(x)=x` on the input `arr=arrays[i]`, broadcasts to the shape of the output. There's no efficiency lost in using the `identity` function for this; `broadcast!` generates a specialized function based on the given function, number of arguments, and number of dimensions of the result.

Comment: Julia has `[CartesianIndex()]` to create a new axis, like `newaxis` from NumPy.

Answer (score 6):

If you're running julia 0.4, you can do this:

```
julia> function mgrid(mapsize)
           T = typeof(CartesianIndex(mapsize))
           indices = Array(T, mapsize)
           for I in eachindex(indices)
               indices[I] = I
           end
           indices
       end
```

It would be even nicer if one could just say

```
indices = [I for I in CartesianRange(CartesianIndex(mapsize))]
```

I'll look into that :-).

Answer (score 4):

I guess this is the same as the MATLAB `meshgrid` functionality. I've never really thought about the generalization to more than two dimensions, so its a bit harder to get my head around.

First, here is my completely general version, which is kinda crazy but I can't think of a better way to do it without generating code for common dimensions (e.g. 2, 3)

```
function numpy_mgridN(dims...)
    X = Any[zeros(Int,dims...) for d in 1:length(dims)]
    for d in 1:length(dims)
        base_idx = Any[1:nd for nd in dims]
        for i in 1:dims[d]
            cur_idx = copy(base_idx)
            cur_idx[d] = i
            X[d][cur_idx...] = i
        end
    end
    @show X
end
X = numpy_mgridN(3,4,5)
@show X[1][1,2,3]  # 1
@show X[2][1,2,3]  # 2
@show X[3][1,2,3]  # 3
```

Now, what I mean by code generation is that, for the 2D case, you can simply do

```
function numpy_mgrid(dim1,dim2)
    X = [i for i in 1:dim1, j in 1:dim2]
    Y = [j for i in 1:dim1, j in 1:dim2]
    return X,Y
end
```

and for the 3D case:

```
function numpy_mgrid(dim1,dim2,dim3)
    X = [i for i in 1:dim1, j in 1:dim2, k in 1:dim3]
    Y = [j for i in 1:dim1, j in 1:dim2, k in 1:dim3]
    Z = [k for i in 1:dim1, j in 1:dim2, k in 1:dim3]
    return X,Y,Z
end
```

Test with, e.g.

```
X,Y,Z=numpy_mgrid(3,4,5)
@show X
@show Y
@show Z
```

I guess `mgrid` shoves them all into one tensor, so you could do that like this

```
all = cat(4,X,Y,Z)
```

which is still slightly different:

```
julia> all[1,2,3,:]
1x1x1x3 Array{Int64,4}:
[:, :, 1, 1] =
 1

[:, :, 1, 2] =
 2

[:, :, 1, 3] =
 3

julia> vec(all[1,2,3,:])
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3
```

Comment: Awesome! I modified the code a bit to get the one-tensor result: 
2nd line: `X = Array(Int, tuple(unshift!([i for i=dims], length(dims))...))` ;
8th line: `X[d, cur_idx...] = i`